# Nested relation subsets of the free group/nested normal groups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm wondering if R is a set of relations contained in another set of relations R' in a free group, then the quotient groups of their normal closures will also be nested up to isomorphism. My intuition was that if a normal subgroup is contained in another normal subgroup, then the quotient group of the larger group must be isomorphic to a subgroup of the quotient group of the smaller group. However, I only seem to be able to find a well-defined homomorphism from the quotient group of the smaller subgroup to the quotient group of the larger subgroup...which is the opposite of what I'm trying to prove?

My goal is to show that adding relations to a group generated by a set of relations will give subgroups.

Comment: In general quotient groups are not isomorphic to subgroups. For example $Q_8$ has $C_2 \times C_2$ as a quotient group but not a subgroup. So the corresponding quotients of a rank $2$ free group will not have the property that you would like.

Comment: But I thought that in the counter-example you gave, you'd have to show that C2xC2 is not a subgroup of a quotient group of a smaller normal subgroup of Q8? Not that C2xC2 is not a subgroup of Q8 itself?

Comment: You wrote: My intuition was that if a normal subgroup is contained in another normal subgroup, then the quotient group of the larger group must be isomorphic to a subgroup of the quotient group of the smaller group. In my example, the quotient group of the larger normal subgroup is $C_2 \times C_2$, which is not a subgroup of the quotient group of the smaller normal subgroup, which is $Q_8$.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't perfectly phrased, but I still think you're missing my point. I'm saying if N is a normal subgroup of M and M is a normal subgroup of G, then G/M is a normal subgroup of G/N. In the case you  mentioned, C2xC2 is a quotient group of Q8. Don't you have to show that C2xC2 then is not a subgroup of another quotient group Q8/N? Sorry, just trying to understand!

Comment: Or maybe I'm just not getting the example. What's the group and what are the 2 nested normal subgroups?

Comment: Also, going back to the context, does adding new relations not restrict us to subgroups of the group generated by the original relations? Or that's true and I'm using the wrong tools to prove it?

Comment: Why don't you ask your question precisely using mathematical symbols rather than trying to explain it in words?

Comment: Thank you for trying!

Comment: I have been trying to convince you that what you are trying to prove is wrong. It is simply not true in general that adding new relations gives subgroups.

Comment: Thank you! That's all I wanted to know. I'll try my best to understand why. :)